# jQuery animate with opacity

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, slider, opacity, fadein

I just wrote jquery animate with opacity and is work great with animation that going to left from right with opacity 0.5, but is not working from left to right in animate but is works fine in fadein.

please take look at the code

```
$(window).load(function() {

  $('#apDiv1').animate({top:"640px"},3000);

  setTimeout(function(){

      $('#apDiv12').fadeIn(2000).animate({left:"340px"},3000);

      setTimeout(function(){
          $('#apDiv12').animate({left:"30px", opacity: 0},3000);
      }, 6300);

  }, 3300);

});
```

AS you can see the first #apDiv12 line where it said .fadeIn, I want to change to animate but is not working and i do not understand why second #apDiv12 is working with animate.

my question is that in

`$('#apDiv12').fadeIn(2000).animate({left:"340px"},3000);`

I want to use .animate instead of fadeIn but is not working in animate, i wonder why! and how solve that!

what does two different with both almost same code! how can i solve it to use animate instead of .fadeIn!

please help thanks.

AM

Comment: fadeIn is shorthand for animate, so actually you are using animate already on both, just behind the scenes on fadeIn...

Comment: This looks like it's working: http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/Q9vng/

Comment: The problem might be that the opacity is not set, so it is animating from `opacity:1` to `opacity:1`.  In my fiddle, I set it using CSS, but if you want better browser support, you can set it with jquery using `fadeTo` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I totally understand your question, but couldn't you just do something like this to "fade in" the element using animate:

```
$('#apDiv12').animate({opacity: 1}, 2000).animate({left:"340px"},3000);
```

Comment: sorry for confusing, what i'm trying to say that how can i solve this in animate on this line of code instead of using .fadeIn! $('#apDiv12').fadeIn(2000).animate({left:"340px"},3000); because is not working in animate.